# Script to name form response spreadsheet based on form title in Google Drive

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I need a script to be able to create the form response spreadsheet of a Google Form and name that Spreadsheet the same as the Form + (Responses) at the end of the name. I have no idea how to do this. I am guessing it has to do with the script below, but the script does not understand that "Title" is the same as a "Name". (I do not know how to append the "(Responses)" part at the end either.) Any help would be appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('FORM ID HERE').getTitle();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(form);
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and also how to apply it to many forms in a folder. The answer is below.

```
function myFunction() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B6Eeub3cEBoobnpxWXdjSWxJRm8").getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();      
      var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId());
      var formName = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getName();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(formName + ' (Responses)');
      form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());  
    }  
 }
```